# How to get the response of Firebase Messaging in django (FCM-DJANGO)

Tags: python, django, firebase, push-notification

I'am trying to get the response errors from Firebase_Admin in my django application, because some users are not reciving the notifications, but when I use the code below I only recive a FirebaseResponseDict() with a batchResponse, the registration_ids_sent and deactivated_registration_ids inside
for example:

`FirebaseResponseDict(response=<firebase_admin.messaging.BatchResponse object at 0x053E124>, registration_ids_sent=['...','...','...'],deactivated_registration_ids=[]`
I need the error detail to know why some users are not reciving push notifications

I need the error detail to know why some users are not reciving push notifications

This is my Code:
`

```
devices.send_message(Message(webpush=WebpushConfig(notification=WebpushNotification(title=noticia.titulo, body=noticia.resumo, image=noticia.capa.url, icon=icone), fcm_options=WebpushFCMOptions(link='https://site/'+str(id)))))
```

`
any help will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same issue but it was resolved with chrome or browser permission.
If you are using Web App
Some of your users might not have given notification permissions for Crop App on their mobile. You have to get it from user

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your suggestion.